# JSON vs WordPress Schema

Tags: php, json, wordpress, forms

I am working on a project that requires dynamic forms creation. This means, that I have a huge amount of forms whose structure I need to store in database and need to give that structure to my client side so that they can create forms according to those structures. Much like what happens in WordPress. There are two solutions for this problem:

- Store the form structure in json string and store this in the database. For example, this can be my json string:

  ```
  {
    'label': 'username',
    'type': 'text',
    'placeholder': 'Enter user name',
    'required': true
  }
  ```

  Ofcourse, this json needs to be more refined and this is just an example
- The second solution is to use a structure similar to WordPress where I can have a 'post_meta' table that has a foreign key of 'forms' table and these key value elements be somewhat rows in it

What would be a better approach? I find the first option more suitable because it's easy to edit the forms. I would just have to make changes to the json string and store it again. I am not really sure about the second approach though and how I would be able to store different forms in it

Thanks in advance,

**Edit:**

These forms are related to users and their roles. So, I need to maintain the relationships between these forms and other entities of the project

Comment: If you decide upon a NoSQL database (like MongDB) you could store your forms as queryable documents. This way you'd have an ease of implementation and no need to stringify your JSON while being able to build more advanced queries like search by field or field type in the form.

Comment: @ŁukaszMazan yes, I did think about NoSQL and I am still open to the idea. It's just that I need to relate these forms to users and various other attributes. That's why, it would kill the purpose of using NoSQL database

Comment: How do you want to query/edit the information from the database? NoSQL doesn't really block the relationship between the objects.

Comment: @ŁukaszMazan For instance, Form A can be filled out by users whose role is Role X, Y and Z and who belong to departments 1, 2 and 3. Form B can be filled out by users whose role is Role U, V, W and X and who belong to departments 3, 4, 5 and 6. This is sort of a relationship that can exist between forms, roles and departments. There would exist many-to-many relationship between these entities